# Can't configure XAMPPto work with zend

Tags: apache, xampp, configure

Hi I'm trying to install ZF 1.12 with XAMPP .I read everything and did everything exactly as it was written,also configured the "httpd.conf" file like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs/<Your project folder>/public"
ServerName <Your project folder>
ServerAlias www.<Your project folder>
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
<Directory "/xampp/htdocs/new/public">
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

but now when i try to start the server i get the following message:

> 500 Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was >unable to complete your request.

Is there anything else that needs to be done

Answer (score 0):

Your Virtual Host definition is incomplete i.e no closing tag ( this may just have been missed when you copy/pasted.

Lets assume you have created and installed the Framework into `/xampp/htdocs/project1/public`

Lets also assume you want to run this site from a development domain called `project1.dev` i.e this is what you want to enter into the browser address bar.

Lets also assume you are using Apache 2.4.x and therefore need to use the Apache 2.4 syntax for access.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project1/public"
   ServerName project1.dev
   ServerAlias www.project1.dev

   <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/new/public">
      DirectoryIndex index.php
      AllowOverride All
      Require local
   </Directory>
   SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
</VirtualHost>
```

Now you need to edit the `C:\windows\system32\srivers\etc\hosts` and add these 2 lines.

```
127.0.0.1  project1.dev
::1  project1.dev
```

Now run this from a command windows launched using "Run as Administrator"

```
net stop dbscache
net start dnscache
```

And then restart Apache. Alternatively, just reboot.